Using viridis Colormap For Matplotlib Plot Lines
I want to use the viridis colormap, yet it keeps reporting "AttributeError: Line2D.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cmap'". Here is what I attempted to do:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')

df = pd.read_excel('c:\MET_Proj\WakeAngleAndSpatter.xlsm')


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))

axes[0].plot(df.iloc[3:20, 0], df.iloc[3:20, 1], label='Sample 1, 200W 200V', cmap='viridis') 
axes[0].set_xlabel('Length from start (mm)')                                  
axes[0].set_ylabel('Wake Angle (degrees)')
axes[0].legend()

axes[1].plot(df.iloc[3:20, 0], df.iloc[3:20, 2], label='Sample 1, 200W 200V', cmap='viridis')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Length from start (mm)')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Cumulative Spatters')
axes[1].legend()

norm = plt.Normalize(1.min(), 1.max())
line_colors = cmap(norm(1))
plt.show()

If I remove any cmap related arguments, it becomes functional. I am a real beginner on coding so please provide an as broke-down-to-earth solution as possible.
Thank you for the help.

I seem to not be able to upload the Excel file. Can someone help me out on this, too?

plot will only take a single color.  Depending what you are trying to do, you may find one of these examples helpful: Selecting individual colors from a colormap, Plotting multiple lines with a LineCollection

Well, a line in matlotlib has only one color. Therefore, no cmap parameter is admitted. To get what you want, the line could be divided into little chunks, each with a different color. Note that many variations would be possible: coloring depending on distance from the start, on y-value, on x-value, on curvature, on some property of the data, ....

If in the future you would want to include data in your post, you can call print(df.head(20).to_dict('list')) and use that output in df = pd.DataFrame(...)to create the dataframe programmatically.
